# how can I blur an element that is described by bootstrap css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a webpage that uses bootstrap framework: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/ (there's an extended resource bootstrap.min.css added). I would like to change it so the darker background is blurred (exactly like in this tutorial http://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/ ). How can I do it without modifing the bootstrap css file? I tried to replace this line:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
```

with what they suggest on this tutorial:

```
#black{
   -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: url('/media/blur.svg#blur');
    filter: blur(10px);
}
#black p, #black h1{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px
}
```

but all I get is blurred text: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/1/

could you help me with that?

Comment: what do mean by "blurred" ? if you blur a solid color area you get a solid color area...

Comment: On the link you provided randomuser1, what they have is a div which a background-color with blur but also transparent, so anything behind it will also be blurred

Comment: @Canvas - yes, I want to blur the black area, so the text is visible, the black area is blurred and everything below the area is also blurred, but I don't know how to implement it in my existing code in the fiddle) 

Marian Theisen - blurred like in this tutorial http://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/

Comment: like that ? http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/14/

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial it said, you need extra block on which you will use the blur filter, and this block must be underneath or your block with content:

```
#search-bg {
  /* Absolutely position it, but stretch it to all four corners, then put it just behind #search's z-index */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 99;

  /* Pull the background 70px higher to the same place as #bg's */
  background-position: center -70px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: url('/media/blur.svg#blur');
  filter: blur(10px);
}

#search {
  /* Put this on top of the blurred layer */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(34,34,34); /* for IE */
  background: rgba(34,34,34,0.75);
}
```